# Mac-OSX Text Navigation

Tags: macos, mac, text-editing

In the terminal I'm able to hit option+b to move back a word.  In any GUI app I get an integral: ∫  I know most of the emacs motions so moving around would be a lot easier if I could use the alt/meta/option movements.  opiton+e doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/walter/additional-mac-os-x-emacs-key-bindings/blob/master/DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Comment: if you found an appropriate answer, consider adding it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: You can also use KeyRemap4MacBook: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68716/emacsify-osx-throughout-word-forward-f-and-word-backward-b-instead/71087#71087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this file to `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` does the trick:

https://github.com/walter/additional-mac-os-x-emacs-key-bindings/blob/master/DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Answer (score 0):

In a C-shell, (tcsh, zsh, csh), a built-in command called `bindkey` will display all the bindings for various navigation and selection shortcuts. While the command does not exist in the other shells, at least several bindings work in /bin/bash and /bin/sh that I've tested.

If `bindkeys` gives you a "command not found" error, enter `tcsh`, and try again at the new prompt. You can redirect the output from bindkey to a file which you can reference later.  Once you're finished with tcsh, type `exit` and you'll go back to your regular command line shell.

Many of the bindings listed also work in TextEdit.app, or on the URL bar of web browsers.

Note that `^` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and `^]` means <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Not all of the key bindings are applicable in every application.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is what you want but you can still use the mac os shortcut using :

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> one word left

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> one word right

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> beginning of line

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> end of line

Comment: I wanted emacs key bindings.

Comment: ⌘+← and ⌘+→ don't bring me to the beginning of the line, they cycle through Terminal windows.